# Вывести дочерние узлы кроме первого и последнего

Tags: javascript, dom

Привет, как вывести дочерние узлы кроме первого и последнего?

```js
document.body.firstElementChild;
```

```html
</html><!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Other</p>
    <p>Next</p>
    <p>Last</p>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
 
 
 
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У вас в начале тег `</html>` лишний

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (document.body.children) {
  const children = document.body.children;

  for (var i = 1; i < children.length - 1; ++i) {
    console.log(children[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Альтернативный вариант - использовать свойство [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)

```
const el = document.body.firstElementChild;

while((el = el.nextElementSibling) && el.nextElementSibling){
  console.log(el);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же задача, только более "занимательно".
Получить первый div и все его дочерние узлы, кроме первого и последнего.
Может кому то поможет.

```
let childEl = document.body.firstElementChild.children;

    for (let i = 0; i < childEl.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) continue;
        if (i === childEl.length - 1) continue;
            console.log(childEl[i]);
    }
```